# wso2is start in developer mode

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm working with WSO2 Identity Server and I'm curious if there is a way to run the product in developer mode without building each component of identity server. I found a way to start the "My Account" component in dev mode by following this tutorial ( https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/setting-up-my-account-in-a-dev-environment/ )
but I want to be able to modify different components such as recovery-portal and authentication-portal by forking and cloning the required github repositories and starting the entire app in developer mode in order to see the code changes in real-time.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK the developer mode will work only for the MyAccount and Console. You can refer to the [doc](https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/master/README.md#run-in-dev-mode) for more details on that.

The recovery portal, the authentication portal etc. cannot be tried with the developer mode. However, there are two ways that you can try this.

1. Build the war files manually and add them to the **WebApps** directory. If the server is running, war file changes will automatically get deployed. If the server is not running, you have to delete the existing directory and restart the server.
2. You can do the changes to the JSPs that are deployed inside the pack. Once the changes are done, you can save the changes and the changes will automatically get deployed.

Comment: This is what I know too but I was curious if is any other way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The reason behind this is that MyAccount and Console are developed using ReactJS, whereas the others are traditional web-apps using JSP/Servlet technologies. Traditional web-apps need to follow a different dev process than ReactJS apps.